# Is it possible to get a list of tables which don't have a specific extended property?

Tags: sql-server, extended-properties

First things first: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (if you need more information, just tell me).

Here is my problem: I have a really high number of tables and I am trying to bring some structure to it.

My team decided to 'just' add certain extended properties to each table:

- Name
- Date
- Link to Doku

Each table should have at these 3 ext. properties. And of course there should be an info at the value of each of them.

Now I am trying to use a script to get all the tables which do NOT have those extended properties.

So the result of the script should be:

A list of all tables which

- missing one or more of the "must have" extended properties
- missing the value of one or more of the "must have" extended properties

At the end a result table would be nice - something like

| TableName | Problem |
| --- | --- |
| Table_A | Missing ext. property |
| Table_B | missing value |

I tried things like

```
select t.name as tablename, p.* 
from sys.tables t
left join sys.extended_properties p on t.object_id = p.major_id
```

to get a list of all tables and ext. properties.

But I have no clue to get the list I was talking about at the beginning.

Any ideas?

Chris

Comment: What are the **actual** `@name = N''` strings used with `sp_addextendedproperty`?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Those are the actual strings: 'Autor', 'Datum', 'JIRA_Link'

Comment: I am using SQL Server Version 2019.
The actual strings are: 'Autor', 'Datum' and 'JIRA_Link'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query will return a row for each `TABLE` in the database, with columns reporting the presence (or absence) of those named extended-properties, as well as an indication if the extended-properties exist but have an empty `@value = N''` string.

**DBFiddle example**: https://dbfiddle.uk/r3lLCcR1

- When...

  - `Table_A` has EPs for `'Name'`, `'Date'`, and `'Link'`.
  - `Table_B` has EPs for `'Name'` and `'Date'`, but not `'Link'`. And the `'Date'` EP is an empty-string.
  - `Table_C` has no EPs.
- ...the result:

  | `TableSchema` | `TableName` | `HasName` | `HasDate` | `HasLink` | `HasNonemptyName` | `HasNonemptyDate` | `HasNonemptyLink` |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | `dbo` | `Table_A` | **true** | **true** | **true** | **true** | **true** | **true** |
  | `dbo` | `Table_B` | **true** | false | **true** | false | false | **true** |
  | `dbo` | `Table_C` | false | false | false | false | false | false |

---

```sql
WITH eps AS (

    SELECT
        ep.major_id AS "object_id",
        ep."name"   AS epName,
        CONVERT( nvarchar(4000), ep."value" ) AS epValue
    FROM
        sys.extended_properties AS ep
    WHERE
        ep.class = 1
        AND
        ep.minor_id = 0
        AND
        ep."name" IN ( N'Name', N'Date', N'Link' )
        AND
        SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY( ep."value", 'BaseType' ) = 'nvarchar'
),
j AS (
  
    SELECT
        OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME( t."object_id" ) AS TableSchema,
        t."name" AS TableName,
        e.epName,
        e.epValue
    FROM
        sys.tables AS t
        LEFT OUTER JOIN eps AS e ON t."object_id" = e."object_id"
),
epCols AS (

    SELECT
        TableSchema,
        TableName,
        CONVERT( bit, COUNT( CASE WHEN j.epName = N'Name' THEN 1 END ) ) AS HasName,
        CONVERT( bit, COUNT( CASE WHEN j.epName = N'Date' THEN 1 END ) ) AS HasDate,
        CONVERT( bit, COUNT( CASE WHEN j.epName = N'Link' THEN 1 END ) ) AS HasLink,

        CONVERT( bit, COUNT( CASE WHEN j.epName = N'Name' AND LEN( j.epValue ) > 0 THEN 1 END ) ) AS HasNonemptyName,
        CONVERT( bit, COUNT( CASE WHEN j.epName = N'Date' AND LEN( j.epValue ) > 0 THEN 1 END ) ) AS HasNonemptyDate,
        CONVERT( bit, COUNT( CASE WHEN j.epName = N'Link' AND LEN( j.epValue ) > 0 THEN 1 END ) ) AS HasNonemptyLink
    FROM
        j
    GROUP BY
        TableSchema,
        TableName
)
SELECT
    TableSchema,
    TableName,
    
    HasName,
    HasDate,
    HasLink,
    HasNonemptyName,
    HasNonemptyDate,
    HasNonemptyLink

FROM
    epCols

ORDER BY
    TableSchema,
    TableName
```

Comment: Hi Dai,
Thank you for your answer! I haven't thought about such a table - I really like it :D
I guess, the second "CONVERT" part is meant to be in another way, right? There should be "1" if there is no entry, right?

Comment: ah I just missed the "Non" in "HasNonemtpyName". So it works just fine :)
OC, I will. I did upvote, but this only seems to work at a higher reputation.